# how to take rcp to take daily backup of database from my ubuntu server to my local system?

Tags: server, backup, rsync, postgresql

I found this article http://www.howtogeek.com/135533/how-to-use-rsync-to-backup-your-data-on-linux/ but it looks outdated and I felt I may get a better answer at AsuUbuntu :)

I have a server running ubuntu 12.04 and my laptop has 12.10, now I want to daily take backup of postgres database on the server, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

First, *don't* just rsync a database, or anything else that's getting actively written to. You're likely to get an unusable copy. This is true for most databases, mail spools ... practically any "live" data. This is why you test your backups!

PostgreSQL has an extensive chapter on [backup and restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html), which would be a good starting point.

For basic use a nightly `pg_dump` backups is generally sufficient. If you need more, look into running hot standbys, WAL archiving with PgBarman, etc.

You actually *can* rsync a PostgreSQL database so long as:

- You run `pg_start_backup()` first
- There's nothing writing to the destination other than the rsync
- You run `pg_stop_backup()` afterwards *and copy the required archive files from `pg_xlog`.

Because of the need to copy archives, it's usually best combined with WAL archiving.

Start with basic `pg_dump` dumps:

- `pg_dumpall --globals-only`; plus
- `pg_dump -Fc` for each database

If you need more, I've given you some info on where to look to find what fits your needs best.